# how to update UI by using progressdialog from several instances of asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an activity with an inner (asynctask) class.
I'm trying to create a progress dialog ,and in a "for" loop create several instances of my inner (asynctask) class.
those instances supposed to update the message + progress of the progress dialog.
I created the progress dialog inside the activity and showed it inside the 
asynctask->onProgressUpdate function.

however the progress dialog is not showing up.

Can anyone tell me if there's another way to update the UI ??

Comment: asynctask runs in background thread.. so u can't display the progress dialog in background thread

Comment: @Driod AsyncTask actually runs the onProgressUpdate on the UI Thread. Are you using publishUpdate?

Comment: can you post relative code?

Comment: i'm using publishprogress for updating and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run AsyncTask successively, one by one, and update your dialog on **preExecute** or **postExecute**. And write your **for** loop in **doInBackground**, where **i** is a indicator what task executed.